# Finding Run Time for a Method in Java

Tags: java, runtime

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out how I can calculate the run time of a method. I would like to learn how to find the run time in terms of rank an suit for my cards in a deck class for the code below:

```
public void shuffle(){
    for (int i = size - ; i > 0; i--){
        swap(i, (int)(Math.random() * (i+1)));
        }
    }

protected void swap(int i, int j){
    Card temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[j];
    cards[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));`

Comment: See also `System.currentTimeMillis();`.

Answer (score 0):

Call System.currentTimeNanos() either side of what you want to time, and subtract the first time from the second to find the time elapsed.

Also, just use Collections.shuffle as suggested in one of the comments.